# Creating offline android app using Phonegap and associated memory limitations

Tags: android, cordova

We have a very strong base of iOS apps and salesforce running at the backend. I am trying to get the similar app running on Android but using PhoneGap (not going native).
I had few questions about this:

1. Does PhoneGap put any limitation on how much RAM can be used for an
   app? If yes, how much?
2. Our iOS apps tend to consume upto 100MB of memory when multiple views and data are loaded in the  app, is this feasible using PhoneGap?
3. CORE data gives me a nice GUI to design my local storage, how can that be achieved in Android?
4. Is there any way I can import the exact data model from iOS to android?

I spent quite some time searching this but did not get any satisfactory answer. All your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PhoneGap doesn't put any limits on how much memory is used. If there are any sort of memory limits it would come from the OS itself.
2. If you can build it as a website, you can build it with PhoneGap. The only thing to watch out for is if you don't manage your DOM structure you could actually [crash the WebView](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/creating-apps-with-phonegap-lessons.html), but if you manage it well you should be fine.
3. Unfortunately with PhoneGap, especially with offline apps, the only two options you have are [localStorage and Web SQL](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).
4. AFAIK there is no way of exporting the data model to Android that would be usable with PhoneGap. The closest would be to go though and try to recreate through one of the storage options I listed in 3 that are supported and well documented with PhoneGap.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It has given me some ground to make a decision.